# Count number of rows for each column in a data frame/table

Tags: r

This is a simple question, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A = c(NA, 0.57, 0.60, 0.51), 
  B = c(NA, 0, 0.09,0.19), 
  C = c(0., 0.05, 0.07, 0.05), 
  D = c(0.23, 0.26, 0.23, 0.26)
)
View(df1)
#   A       B       C       D  
# 1 NA      NA      0.00    0.23
# 2 0.57    0.00    0.05    0.26
# 3 0.60    0.09    0.07    0.23
# 4 0.51    0.19    0.05    0.26
```

I need to get the sum of each column and divide by the number of rows in each column that are neither `NA` nor `0.00` The result should be:

```
#    A       B       C       D
# 1  0.56    0.14    0.06    0.25
```

I tried `df2 <- apply(df1, 2, function(x) colSums(df1, na.rm = T) /length(which(x !=0)))` but it returns a 4x4 matrix. I suspect the problem is with `length(which(x !=0))`. Please advice.

Comment: `sapply(df1, function(x) sum(x,na.rm = T) /length(which(x !=0)))`

Comment: You should try to stop think loops and start think Rish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
round(colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)/colSums(df1!=0, na.rm=TRUE), 2)
#   A    B    C    D 
# 0.56 0.14 0.06 0.24
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr:

```
df1 %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(round(sum(.)/sum(.!=0),2))) 

#      A    B    C    D
#  1 0.56 0.14 0.06 0.24
```